# Django: Writing Model Field-Value into another Models Dropdown List?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I got a Model "PC_Configuration" with a bunch of Dropdown-Lists:

```
class PC_Configuration(models.Model):
PROCESSOR_CHOICES = (
    ('None', 'Wähle deinen Prozessor'),
    ('1', 'Prozessor1'),
    ('2', 'Prozessor2'),
    ('3', 'Prozessor3'),
)

GRAPHICSCARD_CHOICES = (
    ('None', 'Wähle deine Grafikkarte'),
    ('1', 'Grafikkarte1'),
    ('2', 'Grafikkarte2'),
    ('3', 'Grafikkarte3'),
)

OS_CHOICES = (
    ('None', 'Wähle dein Betriebssystem'),
    ('1', 'Betriebssystem1'),
    ('2', 'Betriebssystem2'),
    ('3', 'Betriebssystem3'),
)

RAM_CHOICES = (
    ('None', 'Wähle deinen Arbeitsspeicher'),
    ('1', 'RAM1'),
    ('2', 'RAM2'),
    ('3', 'RAM3'),
)

HARDDRIVE_CHOICES = (
    ('None', 'Wähle deine Restspeicher-Größe'),
    ('1', 'Festplatte1'),
    ('2', 'Festplatte2'),
    ('3', 'Festplatte3'),
)

processor = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=PROCESSOR_CHOICES, default='None')
graphicscard = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=GRAPHICSCARD_CHOICES, default='None')
ram = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=RAM_CHOICES, default='None')
os = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=OS_CHOICES, default='None')
harddrive = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=HARDDRIVE_CHOICES, default='None')
```

I just tested the Choices of those Dropdown-Fields with some Hardcoded Inputs, but I actually want to get all Data for the Choices of e.g. the **"processors"**-Dropdown-Field from the Table of the field **name** of the Model **Processors**:

```
class Processors(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

So my question is: Is it possible to get all the values inside the **name**-Fields of the **Processors-Model**, maybe write them into a Array just like the current Hardcoded Input for being able to show them inside the Dropdown-Field of the **PC_Configuration** Model?

Short Edit:
I've tried to use something like:

```
list(PC_Configuration.objects.all().values_list('name', flat=True))
```

But it seems like "PC_Configuration.objects" isn't existing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a ForeignKey to that table in your model lets say:

```
processor = models.ForeignKey(Processors, models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Than you can create a model form for PC_Configuration

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PC_Configuration

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['processors'].quereset = Processors.objects.all()
        self.fields['processors'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "%s" % obj.name
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! That's a really good idea. But as I just edited, it seems like "Processors.objects" or generally "Model.objects" is not defined. Is there anything I need to import, to get it?

Comment: It should work without importing anything. Objects is the default manager as saying here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects

Comment: @Cptain_Whitebeard did you actually _run_ the code or is that just your IDE speaking? `objects` is added dynamically by Django in the models meta (Not to be confused with the `Meta` class you can declare on Django models) class so unless your IDE is configured for working with Django it would show you that as a warning / error.

Comment: I didn't run it. You guys are right. I'm so into "if it's not in the autocorrect-list, then it's not there" - I'm Sorry. It is working now! Thank you very much. But there's one little problem left: It is currently not showing the value of the row, it is only saying "Processors object (1), Processors object (2) etc.". How do I get the stringvalue?

Comment: Also I can't save it atm. It says "table login_pc_configuration has no column named processor_id" do I need to add that one?

Comment: @Cptain_Whitebeard you need to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` each time you change your models to migrate the changes to your DB. To get a user readable string value define the `__str__` method for your model.

Comment: Hmm deleted the migration-File and reruned the commands, but it still gives me that error.